# Lotus notes won't archive

Tags: lotus-notes

I have an existing user who cannot currently archive in Lotus Notes 8.5.

She is set up to the same settings as everyone else, with the archive folder being located on a server, but her archiving says nothing is being archived when she runs a manual archive.

There also seems to be no trace of her `a_username.nsf` file nor the `l_username.nsf` file on the server share where everyone else's lives.

When she clicks on the archive criterion in the folder list, it says her nsf doesn't exist.

I am not very well clued-up on Lotus Notes, and I can't seem to force the system to make her archive databases.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: What errors are you seeing on the mail archive server (assuming it's domino rather than a file server)?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a server based archive you have to configure your Domino server to run the archive task based on a schedule. This will create the archive database based on the archive profile in the users mailfile.
You can run the archive task once manually by issuing "load compact -a" on the console.